# My file isn't opening in cmd

Tags: java, windows, bluej

Hi I am totally new in Java and don't know much about it .I Have just made a program and not sure if it's correct.I want a input from user so that it will calculate the answer.Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class  Vedant
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner inputa=new Scanner(System.in);
            int b=inputa.nextInt();
            if(b<20);
            int a=5;
            {
                System.out.println("Answer ="+a);
            }
        }
}
```

When I run this file in cmd it does nothing.It doesn't even ask for input.If I type random things and press enter it gives me this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Vedant.main(Vedant.java:8)
```

Please help.And yeah I am just a beginner

Comment: You don't ask for a input, add `System.out.println("Please enter a Number:");` to show an output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run this file in cmd it does nothing.

That's incorrect

> It doesn't even ask for input

You didn't tell it to, the command you gave is `inputa.nextInt()` which only reads input, but doesn't output anything.

> If I type random things and press enter it gives me this

`inputa.nextInt()` means "read the next input as a number". If you're typing random things it can't convert it to a number.

There are some more issues with your code:

```
if(b<20);
```

The semicolon at the end means that nothing is done if  `b` actually is less than 20

```
int a=5;
{
    System.out.println("Answer ="+a);
}
```

The parentheses are not needed here, and because you explicitly set the variable `a` to 5 your application, if it gets this far, will always say `Answer =5`

Comment: Yup.Thank you Fixed that out.But How do I put a range in if..Like if 0<b<20 ??I tried it and it says :bad operand types for binary operators <

Comment: Generally you write those as `b > 0 && b < 20`

Comment: Thank you soo much.Fixed it.Now I just need an idea.Suppose the the input is between 1-20 the answer will be 5 right..I will make more of these ranges like 20-40=10...here is an example what I want to do:Suppose today I input it a number like 7 the answer should be 5.The next day I will input another no. like 10 the input will be 5 too.I want it to save and add the numbers automatically.I am going to do this everyday till June so that the input is 15.If I enter it again the next to next day and the input is 8 the output should add up to 15 like 5+5+5

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting it to ask for a number. You have to tell it to ask for a number like so.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number.");
```

By what you typed in your code it seems like you are trying to add 'b' and 'a' for "Answer". If so, it will be easier for you to make a new variable that is adding 'a' and 'b'.

```
int answer = a + b;
System.out.printf("Answer = %d", answer);
```